# CSV import via PHPMyAdmin, blank timestamp results in 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, timestamp

The destination table has a column named `updated` and is set as:

```
Name: updated
Type: timestamp
Attributes: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
Null: No
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
Extra: ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The source data is in a CSV, where the `updated` field is blank for every row, e.g.

```
id,item_name,updated,quantity
1,car,,4
2,truck,,5
3,chair,,5
```

After importing using PHPMyAdmin, I expect to see the `updated` column filled with the current date/time when the import was executed, however, I get all `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead.

MySQL version: 5.5.30. This result is the same with MyISAM and InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the field is supplied. It is supplied as empty string, which is something different than `NULL` or default.

Empty strings will be converted to `0` when cast to a numeric value. And timestamp `0` formatted as a date is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

You can either run `UPDATE table SET updated=NOW()` after importing (if you always import a complete set) or remove the entire column from the CSV.

Comment: Could also set a default on the column for NOW() in case they want a time entered time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

How do you do a SET updated in phpmyadmin?

With the column described above, assign each value of the update column in the CSV as "NULL". The date of csv import is then added to mySQL.

One strange thing I noticed was errors in defining in the column. Even with an empty table, it was telling me that the default value for TIMESTAMP could not be CURRENT_TIME. To fix this, I banged my head on the table three times, changed the type to datetime, saved, then re-edited, and was allowed to change the type to TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps works for setting timestamps to NULL. 
1. Make the default value of the column - updated as NULL (anyhow, you want the timestamp to be empty) 
2. In csv file type NULL instead of keeping the field blank

This method can also be used for auto increments